# Resolving host... message in Chrome and no internet after some fixes on Debian

Tags: debian, internet, lxde

I cannot connect to internet. My chrome browser still displays *Resolving host...*. The OS is Debian Jessie with LXDE.

My interfaces file is:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I had been having problems with usb modem connection. I found the reason was old Mobile Partner that had been not able to install on Jessie and I had been not uninstalled it completelly. So I removed it manually yesterday and perhaps removed some needed files.

How can I run internet with no application just with interfaces file. And how to debug it?

I am getting internet from my Windows pc via internet sharing connection. Now my Debian shows that the connection is ok, in wicd, in desktop tray but this  *Resolving host...* message is present in Chrome and no site is opened.

Comment: try changing your dns to 8.8.8.8 in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Resolving host depends of the DNS, try editing the /etc/resolv.conf file even if it's temporary just to know if this is the problem or not , here is a link :
[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-bsd-unix-set-dns-nameserver/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 1) install resolvconf app  "sudo apt install resolvconf"
 2) sudo service networking restart
```

Or if resolvconf is already installed:

```
 1) sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
 2) sudo service networking restart
```

The resolvconf program changes /etc/resolv.conf file and acts as an intermediary between programs which use that file (here Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Having tried all the other recommendations offered here and elsewhere, the *only* approach that has worked for me is to specify the use of OpenDNS servers. Which is to say that my Linux system now avoids the use of Google's DNS servers as recommended "everywhere else". See, inter alia:

**-->** https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007087-Ubuntu

I specified OpenDNS servers `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`, then rebooted. My *Resolving host* issues were not only solved, the *Resolving hosts* status message appeared for perhaps 0.2 seconds rather than "hang" forever...